# div float a part on the left, list on the right (but this must be at the far right) and no reverse in HTML?

Tags: html, css, css-float

i am trying on a footer to put an element on the far left:
--MY WEB SITE (aligned on the right)--

On the far right (the end of the list must be aligned with the right border of the browser), i want  to put in order:
twitter, facebook, newsletter

By floating left, what i get is the opposite of the html file

Thanks all

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6pa3L30/)

```
<div class=footer>
<UL><H4>MY WEB SITE (aligned on the right)</H4>
<LI><a href=https://www.linkedin.com/pub/ric style='border-bottom:     0px'></A><LI>
<LI>twitter</LI>
<LI><a href=https://www.facebook.com/ric style="text-decoration : none;border-bottom: 0px">facebook</A></LI>
<LI><a href=newsletter.php style="text-decoration : none;border-bottom: 0px"><font color='#0894D2 '>NEWSLETTER</FONT></A></LI>
</UL>
</DIV>


.footer {
 border: 2px solid grey;
    width:90%;
height:auto;
text-align: center;
}


.footer:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}


.footer ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
}

.footer ul li {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
display:inline-block;
font-size:12px;
float:right;
}



.footer h4{
  margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
display:inline-block;
font-size:12px;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: your first li missing a closing tag too ?

Comment: yes i missed the slash to close li tag

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change an order of your list items on the right side, just try to change an order of list items tags in html...

```
<div class="footer">
        <ul>
            <h4>MY WEB SITE (aligned on the right)</h4>
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/ric" style='border-bottom: 0px'></a></li>
            <li><a href="newsletter.php" style="text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px"><font color='#0894D2 '>NEWSLETTER</font></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ric" style="text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px">facebook</a></li>
            <li>twitter</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML as such:

```
<div class="footer">
<H4>MY WEB SITE (aligned on the right</H4>
<ul>
    <li><a href="newsletter.php" style="text-decoration : none;border-bottom: 0px"><font color="#0894D2 ">NEWSLETTER</font></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ric" style="text-decoration : none;border-bottom: 0px"><img src="images/facebook.png" />Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/ric" style='border-bottom: 0px'><img src="images/linkedin.jpg" />LinkedIn</a><li>
    <li>twitter<div id="logo_twitter"></div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first....

In order to achieve what you are looking for (hope I understood corectly), you should put the H4 tag outside UL. Then, in CSS, set the UL (*footer ul*) to *float:right* and the the LIs (*footer ul li*) to *float:left*.

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/w6pa3L30/4/

```
.footer ul{float:right;}
.footer ul li {float:left;}
```

Now, you should also review your code. *FONT* tag is not supported in HTML5. You should also avoid using divs for displaying social icons (I guess that is what you wanted to do inside Twitter LI), instead use *span* tag. I would also recommend you to avoid using inline styling; style them inside your stylesheet.

Comment: OK, that was my mistake. H4 in the UL, because i wanted to have all element in one line/one group. Div footer was for that. Thanks all for making advancing a noob